# Before the daily fire ritual - what is the purification?

Tags: brahmins, vedic-rituals, agni, sruti, rites

This information coming from a Tamil Brahmin based on reference to Mahaperiyava's instructions and
book  on Achamanam  written by  the great Vedic Scholar   Sri Sharma  Sastrigal.

Aachamana
a.A Brahmin becomes purified by  Aachamana  when the water swallowed reaches  the heart, A kshatriya  when it reaches the throat  , a Vaishya when it reaches the palate  and a Shudhra  or a lady when it touches   their lips.

There are do and don'ts specified before and after.
Any holy work done without achamanam is a rakshasa work.
Also every sect follows bit different. Also there is one for srouthas.
I had mentioned in the answer on fire ritual that preliminaries would be discussed...

From Mahaperiyava and Sri Sharma Sastrigal.
Source of information:
http://brahminrituals.blogspot.com/2016/06/achamanam-procedure-of-purification.html